# Phonegap build fails with splash screen

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm attempting to use the new phonegap build with CLI 7.0.1

The build fails with this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileAssetCatalog /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Our_HNZC_Learning_space-ddfmniquktwfmabpvilymbvzreak/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Our\ HNZC\ Learning\ space/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Our\ HNZC\ Learning\ space.app Our\ HNZC\ Learning\ space/Images.xcassets
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/private/project/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-workspace,Our HNZC Learning space.xcworkspace,-scheme,Our HNZC Learning space,-configuration,Release,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,Our HNZC Learning space.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/private/project/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/private/project/build/sharedpch
```

I've added these to config.png

```
<icon src="res/icon.png" />
<splash src="res/splash.png" />
```

And I've added this plugin

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" />
```

And the files are in the right place.

Splash works fine, Icon is causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the exact problem is based upon the info you provided.

A starting point would be to remove the splashscreen plugin and re-add it:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova prepare
```

I would suggest using an Icon and Splashscreen generator such as this one: http://phonegap.appiq.software/

It does all of the hard work for you and gives you the exact code for your config.xml

I hope this is helpful.